# Launching program several times

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I am using Mac Os. This is command line code to lauch my programm (two parts)

```
nucmer --mum file1.txt file2.txt

show-snps -Clr -x 2 out.delta > out_file1.snps
```

First part of the programm creates file out.delta. My file2.txt is always the same, but I want to launch this both parts 35000 times whith different file1.txt. All the file1s are located in the same directory.

Is it possible to do it using BASH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep all the input files in a directory. Create a wrapper script to invoke `nucmer` script and then `show-snps` script. Your wrapper script will accept path to file directory as input. Iterate over all files in the directory and call your two scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along these lines:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print | grep -v './out_' | while read f
do
  b=$(basename ${f})
  nucmer --mum ${f} file2.txt
  show-snps -Clr -x 2 out.delta > out_${b}.snps
done
```

The `find` bit finds all files in the current directory. `grep` filters out any previous output files, in case you've run some previously. The `basename` line strips off the leading `./` and trailing extension, and then your two programs get run with the input file name and an output filename based on the basename output.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get an argument list too long error, you could just use for:

`for f in file*.txt; do nucmer --mum $f second.txt; show-snps -Clr -x 2 out.delta > out_${f%.txt}.snps; done`